# Why does last data of I2C DMA transfer break?

Tags: i2c, stm32, dma

I used DMA to transfer I2C data, but I always lose the last data. hardware configuration is shown below:

```
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_DR_Address;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)I2C1_Buffer_Tx;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralDST;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 2;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh;
  DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
  DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel6, &DMA_InitStructure);
  DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel6, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
```

The data to be transfered is:

```
  I2C1_Buffer_Tx[0] = 0xF0;
  I2C1_Buffer_Tx[1] = 0x55;
```

When a data frame has been sent, an interrupt of DMA is generated:

```
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_IT_TC6) != RESET)
  {
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel6, DISABLE);
    DMA1_Channel6->CNDTR = 2;
    DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_IT_TC6);
    switch (mode)
    {
      case 1:
        I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
        mode = 2;
        break;
      case 2:
        I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2C1, ENABLE);
        mode = 3;
        break;......
```

When I set a breakpoint at `I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE)`:[image: code sample]

I get SDA signal from oscilloscope in this pattern:[image: SDA before start]

It shows that two data have been sent through SDA:0xF0 and 0x55, however, when I set breakpoint after that code:

[image: code sample 2] and I got following data:
[image: SDA after start]

it shows that only one data has been sent through SDA: 0xF0 and then a restart condition. so, I will lose the last data if I let the whole program run as usual.

I can only explain the phenomenon like this: DMA has already sent two data(0xF0 0x55), and then it generates an interrupt. However, those two data are still in I2C's buffer, then, in DMA's interrupt, it generates a start condition. For some reason, it breaks the final data.

Can any one give some suggestion to fix this problem or I can only set buffersize of DMA n+1 if I want to send n data.

Comment: I seem to recall that it's important to clear the DMA interrupt flag even if you're not using interrupts, and that this a common cause of "first transfer works, second fails"-type problem

Comment: @ScottSeidman, I have cleared the DMA interrupt flag: `DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_IT_TC6);`

Comment: Is that the DMA flag, or the DMA interrupt flag?  They may be two different things

Comment: Never mind-- they IT, of course, is the interrupt!

Comment: @ScottSeidman,DMA has four flags, three of them are all about interrupts: half transfer, transfer complete and global interrupt. the last one is error transfer flag. In this application, I only care about "transfer complete flag":DMA1_IT_TC6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your DMA Handler gets called *before* the last byte is sent, as this is the point in time when the DMA buffer turns empty. It has just been written into the peripherial register.

You need to wait for this byte to be out on the bus - using the I2C interrupt handler for example.

Comment: sorry, I can not understand it .`if(DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_IT_TC6)!=RESET)`shows that DMA has already sent all the data and set transfer complete flag(TC),then the code inside this handler

Comment: The I²C peripherial is still chewing on the last byte when the DMA handler gets called.

Comment: The *DMA* transfer has finished - there are no more bytes left - but the *I²C* is still in progress.

Comment: do you mean that when DMA TC interrupt does not equal to completion of transferring all the data through I2C data bus?